# Gasless transaction and easy token Solidity receiver callbacks for ERC-20 tokens

Tags: erc-20, gas, layer-2

I am planning a token swap for an old pre-ERC-20 token. The new token will have its ledger smart contract written from a scratch. While doing it, I would like to integrate new EIP features to the token core itself.

Some features I hope to add

- Easier approve() for smart contract interaction - permit() as done by MDAI, but could not find official discussion for this
- Gasless transactions or somebody else pays the gas for txs
- Anything that would support microtransactionsn easily or making token transactions scale

Are there any EIP proposals or other proposals out there for microtransactions that would require active support from the token?

Are there wallet support (MetaMask / WalletConnect) and standardisation for layer 2 that I should look into when upgrading the token contract?

Comment: I don't think layer 2 is too interested in the actual token design. As long as you can transfer them (freeze them) they can be used in layer 2 solutions.

Comment: I agree. However sometimes there might be things like `approveAndCall` or some other standardized methods that make L2 integration less painful for users. It would be handy to know about these upfront.

Comment: In the end, I ended up using ERC-777 as with the arguments presented here https://forum.openzeppelin.com/t/emerging-standards-and-recommendations-for-approveandcall-transferandcall-eip-777-and-so-on/2569/3?u=miohtama

Answer (score 1):

1. You may create multiple contracts to interact with erc20 token so as to virtualize the interaction & increase the abstraction.
2. As you create multiple contracts, you may choose only to make calls to initiate the processes that is paid by another contract. Also you can create a private network where miners only work for you.